# How to use bootstrap with java servlets

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, servlets

I need to know how to use bootstrap with java servlets to make my web page more attractive.Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. It's possible. With servlets you can create any HTML you want. All you have to do is include a link for appropriate bootstap css and js files in your html page.

If you are going to pair servlets with JSP, then you will have to create links for bootstrap css and js in the JSP.

Comment: Thanks a lot..ill try it